# Using back-ticks to show code doesn't allow you to start with a space?

Tags: support, comments, code-block

Referring to the comment I made here [MySQLi Select hashtag from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999385/mysqli-select-hashtag-from-table#comment31557441_20999385)

Trying to use `# someTag` did not work so well for me in the comments and same thing goes for this post, edit this post and you will see ` # someTag`

I assume this is on purpose, can anyone enlighten me?

Comment: No, backticks, like `*` and `_` to make text bold and / or italics, must be tight up against the word to prevent single characters used in a sentence to start markup.

Comment: This is a feature of MarkDown, not specific to Stack Exchange.

Comment: @MartijnPieters is there a reason why your explanation does not hold true when comparing a post vs. comment?

Comment: Hrm, trying to find that reason now... that surprised me actually.

Comment: But note how the leading whitespace has been stripped. It doesn't matter how many spaces you put at the start, they are *all* removed from the output.

Comment: I do notice that, but I think we've uncovered an inconsistency between comments and posts now because my comment completely failed to become a code block in my SO comment =)

Comment: @TimStone thanks! I think that is exactly what I was looking for.