# Markdown in comments does not parse backtick code spans with a leading space

Tags: bug, markdown

Markdown in comments does not parse backtick code spans with a leading space, e.g. `` ` foobar` ``. Markdown in posts does.

Example:

[image: Post and comments showing two different parsings of inline code tags.]

Note: I don't know whether this is related to CommonMark, because [apparently it's not used for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark#comment1166937_348747).

Comment: E.g ` yeah you're right` `this works`

Comment: Example without leading space: `foobar`
Example with leading space: ` foobar`

Comment: This has been reported before: [Using back-ticks to show code doesn't allow you to start with a space?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215417/using-back-ticks-to-show-code-doesnt-allow-you-to-start-with-a-space).

Comment: Per the answer to that question, you can start with a zero-width unicode character, then a space. Doing that produces `​ this`, which used {U+200B}.